# Multiple feature inside single feature file

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

My current Cucumber file looks like this:

```
Feature: Test Online application Page

Scenario: Visit application home page and test links

Scenario: Visit application Login and Validate login
```

So now I would like to add few more scenarios may be for API testing in the same file. So i was thinking to create a new Feature for that instead of using the Feature: Test Online application Page. This way i dont need to create a separate feature file for API testing.

```
Feature: Test Online application Page

     Scenario: Visit application home page and test links

     Scenario: Visit application Login and Validate login

Feature: Test application API's

    Scenario: validate Login API
```

Is it possible to have multiple features within a single feature file and is that a good practice? I just need to test one API and I will run API tests along with online tests. I will still separate them using @online and @api tags.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is not possible to have multiple feature inside single feature file. If you create multiple feature inside single feature file, you will get Gherkin Parser exception while running cucumber scenarios. So the answer is NO.

```
C:/Users/ABC/RubymineProjects/XYZ.feature: Lexing error on line 47: 'Feature test google'. See https://github.com/cucumber-attic/gherkin2/wiki/LexingError for more information. (Cucumber::Core::Gherkin::ParseError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is obviously not a good practice. It is best to put a single feature in a feature file. You should create new feature files for doing this. But you can add any number of scenarios in a single feature file.

The corresponding steps may or may not be in a single step file.

Comment: Thanks Philip. Is it possible to have two features inside a single feature file? just curious ... :)

Comment: I m not sure.. havent tried yet.. y dont you try it yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

In BDD, cucumber is designed for the non-technical audience as well.

> - Writing scenario and steps definition in Gherkin Language or simple English is must support other audience.
> - All scenario should be executed Independently. No dependency on other scenario or feature file

In my past experience, Adding more complexity will add more flaky tests and High Maintenance cost

Agree with @philip John

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text file with the features
and when executing the file it adds all the files in the order defined in the file.
@order-execution.txt
In this example, the file was created in the project root. file content

```
./features/records/country.feature
./features/records/company.feature
```

```
   "scripts": {
     "test:company": "cucumber-js @order-execution.txt --tags \"@company\" -f json:result/records/company.json",
   },
```

this is the same as riding this way

```
   "scripts": {
     "company": "cucumber-js ./features/records/country.feature ./features/records/company.feature --tags \"@company\" -f json:result/records/company.json",
   },
```